# When I enable Cloudflare my site doesn't read my CSS file

Tags: cdn, vps, cloudflare

When I enable Cloudflare my site's CSS doesn't get read. I turned off css/html/js minify and rocket loader in the Cloudflare settings but I still get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any other caching plugins? These might be at play as well. If you have changed your CSS file recently, however, you need to go to CloudFlare Development Mode first to bypass our cache (you would want to do this when making changes to any [static content files](http://cloudflare.tenderapp.com/kb/top-frequently-asked-questions/which-kind-of-file-extensions-does-cloudflare-cache) while using CloudFlare).